# Doesn't Virtualservice for internal service cause loop?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

When it comes to virtualservice for internal service (without gateway spec),

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  hosts:
  - nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
  - httpd.default.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - name: nginx
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /nginx
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nginx.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
  - name: httpd
    match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /httpd
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: httpd.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 80
```

This virtualservice sends traffics according to URI /nginx or /httpd,

For example, **curl httpd/httpd** and **curl nginx/httpd** will be sent to httpd server. The sequences will be.. check Hosts in spec and matching against URI will be followed.

However, after that, when the traffic is destined to the final host, the virtualservice is not considered again?

Because the virtualservice is about nginx and httpd service and when the sequence of the virtualservice is ended, the final destination is the same with hosts in spec.

When exactly a virtualservice is considered? Every moment or not when traffic is sent to hosts pertaining to hosts in virtualservice.

Comment: Have you read https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services ? "Clients send requests to the virtual service host as if it was a single entity, and Envoy then routes the traffic to the different versions depending on the virtual service rules. The traffic routing is completely separate from the instance deployment, meaning that the number of instances implementing the new service version can scale up and down based on traffic load without referring to traffic routing at all."

Comment: @Malgorzata  Yes, but I mean in the case of virtualservice for internal service, if the gateway is not specified in virtualservice, the virtualservice is about for internalservice.

Comment: You should split your VirtualService into two separate https://istio.io/latest/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#split-virtual-services. Otherwise you will get 404 error after executing `$ curl nginx/httpd`. However a  `VirtualService`  can only be fragmented this way if it is bound to a gateway. Host merging is not supported in sidecars. Don't worry about gateway - in your case this gateway will be used for internal traffic only.

Comment: @Malgorzata Thank you for your comment, it seems there is a little bit gap in my intention. I will chek out the link. Thank you again.

Comment: Please let me know if provided link helped.